# eshell alias not working properly

Tags: eshell, aliases

the following alias in the aliases file doesn't work in eshell 2.4.2, emacs 24.4.1

> alias ff 'find-file $1'

error message as is is given below

> find-file $1: command not found

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: If eshell aliases are anything like real aliases, they won't have support for arguments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't quote name of command together with its argument. As written,
the code creates an alias for command named `find-file $1` which doesn't
exist, of course.

You need to remove the quotes:

```el
alias ff find-file $1
```

Comment: In the code to eshell-maybe-replace-by-alias which takes command and args as two its arguments in em-alias.el I see no use of its second argument, which seems the problem to me

Comment: Yet it seems to work, thanks. Although most of the info on the web says it should be quoted, see e.g. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellAlias

Comment: @SumProxy, these examples show how you create new alias from within the Emacs shell. This will add corresponding line into alias file. It will be there unquoted. If you want to write aliases directly in the file, you should not quote this stuff.

Comment: [@Mark](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2487/mark) thanks again for proper clarification